# Restrict URL access to users after login via API on Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, session

I am logging in via Laravel API.

Let's say that I am on www.domain.com/login. After login is successful, I put the token into a cookie and redirect to /admin.

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return view('admin');
})->middleware('auth');
```

The problem is that Laravel doesn't see that the user is logged in, thus redirects me to /login once more.

And, if I declare the route as follows

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {
        return view('admin');
    });
```

Everyone can access www.domain.com/admin

I appreciate any help.

Luca

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `auth:api` middleware so it can see the auth user

Comment: Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return view('admin');
})->middleware('auth:api');

Doing this keeps redirecting to the login page.